# Row events in a gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net, events, gridview

I have an asp.net application. I have login window and different groups of users. Every group of users has a different menu. So, i have 2 groups which have same menu item which goes to same page. In that page i have a GridView.
My question: It is possible to make the rows from gridview clickable for a group of users and not clickable for other group?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is absolutely possible. You can use OnRowDataBound event of grid view.

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && **group=="Group1"**)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
        e.Row.Attributes["style"] = "cursor:pointer";
    }
}
```